# layoutAttributesClass not called in UICollectionViewLayout subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When subclassing UICollectionViewLayout and overriding layoutAttributesClass, the class function does not get called. Is this a bug?

overriding in a subclass of  UICollectionViewFlowLayout works though.

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass UICollectionViewLayout class, you should to implement these methods as minimum:

- collectionViewContentSize
- layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:
- layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:
- shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange;